# One canvas, two sets of data

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

So I have two sets of data, lets call them A and B and then one canvas X

So first I do this:

```
var selection=canvas.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(A)                    
selection.enter().append("circle")
selection
   .attr(...)
   .attr(...)
```

So this does what I want and makes my first group of circles. But then I want to make a second group of circles with different properties based on data B so I tried doing the following:

```
var selection2 = canvas.selectAll("circle")
selection2.enter().append("circle").data(B)
selection2
  .attr(...)
  .attr(...)
```

however this doesn't seem to work and selection2 interferes with selection one. How do I get this to work?

Comment: `var selection2 = canvas.selectAll("circle")    selection2.enter().append("circle").data(B)`    
I think you need to put the `.data(B)` on the first line to be consistent with the first dataset

Answer (score 0):

just add them as elements with a different selector...  e.g.

```
var selection2 = canvas.selectAll(".circleb")
selection2.enter().append("circle").data(B)
selection2
  .classed(".circleb")
  .attr(...)
  .attr(...)
```

With your current approach, you're selecting all *circle*  elements (which are currently bound to dataset A), and trying to rebind them to dataset B.  By using a different selector (as per my example) you create a second set of elements bound to dataset B, leaving the original elements bound to dataset A.

edited to fix a night-time blooper (as pointed out in the comments)

Comment: But "circleb" isn't a proper svg type like "circle" or "rect", so wouldn't using that also give me an error of some sort?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. The argument to select all can be whatever you want it to be, but then append has to take in an appropriate svg type. So its:

canvas.selectAll(circle2);
append(circle)